# WSO2 Traffic Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In API Manager, if I do not want throttling, do I need to have [traffic manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-ConfiguringtheTrafficManager) node? Except for throttling, what else it does?

Comment: Read This: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Key+Concepts

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is required only for throttling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you are not using advance throttling you do not need traffic manager Node. Make sure you disable Advance throttling from api-manager.xml refer the following config under  section.

```
<EnableAdvanceThrottling>true</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
```